# Simple image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a simple gallery that hides and shows images. It works fine, however, I am not satisfied with my approach, and my code seems redundant. Can you check my code and give a better idea on how I can improve it?

**HTML**

```html
<div class="big_img_wrapper">
                <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/big_img_1.JPG" id="big_img_1" class="big_img">
                <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/big_img_2.JPG" id="big_img_2" class="big_img">
                <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/big_img_3.JPG" id="big_img_3" class="big_img">
                <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/big_img_4.JPG" id="big_img_4" class="big_img">
                <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/big_img_5.JPG" id="big_img_5" class="big_img">
                <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/big_img_6.JPG" id="big_img_6" class="big_img">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbs_img_wrapper">
                <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_1.jpg" id="thumbs_img_1" calss="thumbs_img">
                <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_2.jpg" id="thumbs_img_2" calss="thumbs_img">
                <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_3.jpg" id="thumbs_img_3" calss="thumbs_img">
                <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_4.jpg" id="thumbs_img_4" calss="thumbs_img">
                <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_5.jpg" id="thumbs_img_5" calss="thumbs_img">
                <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_6.jpg" id="thumbs_img_6" calss="thumbs_img">
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.big_img_wrapper, .big_img_wrapper img{
        width: 370px;
        height: 246px;
        /*display: none;*/
    }
    .thumbs_img_wrapper{
        padding:0;
    }
    .thumbs_img_wrapper img{
        width: 111px;
        height: 70px;
        margin: 14px 0 0 14px;
    }
    #thumbs_img_1, #thumbs_img_4{
        margin: 14px 0 0 0;
    }
```

**jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
    $('img#big_img_1').fadeIn('slow'); // Serve as default image

    $('img#thumbs_img_1').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        $('img#big_img_1').fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });

    $('img#thumbs_img_2').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        $('img#big_img_2').fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });

    $('img#thumbs_img_3').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        $('img#big_img_3').fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });
    $('img#thumbs_img_4').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        $('img#big_img_4').fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });
    $('img#thumbs_img_5').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        $('img#big_img_5').fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });
    $('img#thumbs_img_6').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        $('img#big_img_6').fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });
});
```

Comment: This would be better if it was a snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can keep path in data structure.

```
<div class="big_img_wrapper"></div>
<div class="thumbs_img_wrapper"></div>

<script>
  var i, big_image_urls, thumbs_image_urls, gallery_size;

  big_image_urls = [
    'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/hiring/photos/big/1.jpg',
    'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/hiring/photos/big/2.jpg',
    'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/hiring/photos/big/3.jpg',
    'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/hiring/photos/big/4.jpg',
    'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/hiring/photos/big/5.jpg'
  ];

  thumbs_image_urls = [
    'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/hiring/photos/thumbs/1.jpg',
    'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/hiring/photos/thumbs/2.jpg',
    'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/hiring/photos/thumbs/3.jpg',
    'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/hiring/photos/thumbs/4.jpg',
    'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/hiring/photos/thumbs/5.jpg'
  ];

  i = 0;
  gallery_size = thumbs_image_urls.length;

  while (i < gallery_size) {
    $('.thumbs_img_wrapper').append(
      '<img src="' + thumbs_image_urls[i] + '" id="' + i + '" class="thumbs_img">'
    );
    i++;
  }

  $('.big_img_wrapper').append(
    '<img src="' + big_image_urls[0] + '" id="big_img_' + 0 + '" class="big_img">'
  );

  $('.thumbs_img').click(function(){
    var id;
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.big_img')
      .hide()
      .attr('src', big_image_urls[id])
      .fadeIn('slow');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You have good approach, I appreciate it. I use the approach given earlier and it works fine. I also tried yours and it works fine also, however all the big images are displayed after page reload, and it will only display single image after clicking the thumbnails.

Comment: @Rodge Ugh, sorry. I edited my answer and made an example: jsfiddle.net/ohbzm7ky/2

Comment: thanks khusaenov. It also works fine. I'll try this to my other page.

Comment: @Rodge welcome!

Answer (score 3):

replace all .click() functions with:

```
$('img.thumbs_img').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.replace("thumbs_img_", "big_img_");
        $('img#'+id).fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });
```

Comment: Hey Edan Feiles. This is better however when tried this one, it din't work.

Comment: did you changed the html from `calss=` to `class=`?

Comment: Yah! Thanks again and sorry for my typo errors. The problem now comes when I clicked on the small image, the large one disappear and didn't show the other one.

Comment: Cool! It worked. I replace id = str.replace to id = id.replace and works fine. Thanks guys for your great solutions. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

What's the point of having thumbnails if you're just going to have the user download them *plus* the full sized images up front?  The whole idea behind thumbnails is that you present the user with a smaller version so they can decide for themselves whether or not they want to take the time/spend the bandwidth to view the larger image.

With a few modifications to your markup, you can make this a lot easier for yourself:

```
<div class="thumbs_img_wrapper" id="gallery">
    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_1.jpg" data-full-path="path/to/original_1.jpg" />
    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_2.jpg" data-full-path="path/to/original_2.jpg" />
    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_3.jpg" data-full-path="path/to/original_3.jpg" />
    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_4.jpg" data-full-path="path/to/original_4.jpg" />
    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_5.jpg" data-full-path="path/to/original_5.jpg" />
    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_6.jpg" data-full-path="path/to/original_6.jpg" />
</div>
```

With a little help from event delegation, you can make this very efficient (disclaimer: this probably has some errors, but it will give you an idea of what to do):

```
document.getElementById('gallery').addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
        var fullPath = ev.target.getAttribute('data-full-path');
        // do stuff with fullPath that will load & display the full sized image
    }
});
```

Your images are missing alt attributes.  If it is unrealistic to provide useful alt information due to dynamically content, just use an empty value (eg. `alt=""`).

Your images are also missing dimensions.  Adding dimensions will diminish/eliminate document reflow as the images load.